# How to say "trying to get someone to look at something"

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

What is a good way to express the idea of "trying to get someone to look at something", for example "She's trying to get me to look at her". I tried typing this into [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ja&text=She's%20trying%20to%20make%20me%20look%20at%20her) and got this:

> 彼女は私に彼女を見させようとしている

That doesn't sound right, it sounds like she is a flasher or something, but I'm thinking of someone who keeps trying to get someone else's attention or to appear charming to someone.

Other expressions I thought of are "目を引く", for example

> 彼女は僕の目を引こうとしている

or 注目を浴びる

> 彼女は僕の注目を浴びようとしている

or even

> 僕にみられたがっている

(this is probably completely wrong Japanese though!)

How do these sound, and what is a natural way to express this thought?

Comment: 彼女が気を引こうとしている理由は何なのでしょうか。可愛い服や髪型を自慢したいのか、誕生日のことを思い出して欲しいのかで話が変わってきます。

Comment: narutoさん - どちらかというと可愛い服や髪型を自慢したいのかのようなことです。

Comment: 「気を引く」もいいかもしれないです。そっちの方が性的な意味合いが入ってるような気がします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. 彼女は私に彼女を見させようとしている
> 2. 彼女は僕の目を引こうとしている
> 3. 彼女は僕の注目を浴びようとしている
> 4. 彼女は僕に見られたがっている

1. 文法的には合っていますが、直訳調すぎて自然ではありません。「彼女は自分のことを見させようとしている」なら多少マシになりますが、他の言い方をする方が無難です。
2. 自然な表現だと思います。ただし必ずしも「体や服を見て欲しい」という意味にはなりません。単にテストの結果を自慢したいのかもしれません。
3. 「注目を浴びる」は、普通は多くの人から注目されている時に使われるので、対象が1人だけの時には違和感があります。
4. 表現は自然ですが、彼女の「行動」よりも「気持ち」に焦点が置かれている感じがします。目を引こうと積極的に行動しているのであれば、2. の方が良いと思います。

他の表現としては「彼女は新しい髪型を(僕に)見せたがっている」や「彼女が(僕に)服を[見せつけ](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%9B%E3%81%A4%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B)ようとしてくる」などがシンプルで良いと思います。